# Difficulties getting values from a <select>

Tags: php, select, post

I'm trying to get the user's choice in a `<option>` tag.
The multiple `<option>` tags are generated from data from the database.

Here's the form:

```
    <form action="mudaVideo.php" method="post">

            <label for="sel1">escolher o vídeo</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="apagar">

              <?php

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM video ORDER BY idvideo";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

  while ($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

          $idvideo = $list["idvideo"];
          $titulo = $list["titulo"];
          $subtitulo = $list["subtitulo"];
          $link = $list["link"];

          echo '<option>'.$titulo.'</option>';

  } // end while

               ?>

                <option>wow ate me passo</option> -->
           </select>
        <button type="submit" name="apagar" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar" style="background-color:transparent; color:black;">apagar vídeo</button>

        </div>
      </form>
```

Here's my php:

```
    if(isset($_POST['apagar'])) {


  $id = $_POST['apagar'];

  echo 'a escolha foi ' . $id . '!';

  $sql = "DELETE FROM video
          WHERE idvideo='".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)

    {

   }

   else

   {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
}
```

When I try to echo the value of $id, it's empty, so something wrong is escaping me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the `value` attribute in `<option>`.

For example:

```
<select name="apagar">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

You can solve this by using:

```
echo '<option value="' . $titulo . '">'.$titulo.'</option>';
```

---

Also, both the `<button>` and `<select>` have the same name `apagar`, thus it will have value of the latter as it comes after `<select>`:

```
<select class="form-control" name="apagar">

<button type="submit" name="apagar" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar" style="background-color:transparent; color:black;">apagar vídeo</button>
```

Comment: lol love how we both edited our answers to contain the parts we missed from each others answers :p

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have two form elements with the same name. Your `select` has the name of apagar but so does your `button`. Since the button comes after the select, it overrides the name of the select. You also need a `value=""` with the id of each of your options.